# Django orm filter many to many fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, orm

The question is this. There are Project and User models. In the Project model, there are 2 ManyToMany links to the users model.

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()

    creaters = models.ManyToManyField('User', related_name='creater_projects')
    workers = models.ManyToManyField('User', related_name='worker_projects')

class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I need to filter the projects depending on the transferred user.id

You can filter as follows

```py
from django.db.models import Q

user_id = 1
Project.objects.filter(Q(creaters__id=user_id) | Q(workers__id=user_id))
```

What other ways are there to do similar filtering?

Comment: I'm not really following why you look for other ways. What is wrong with this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use '**__in**' operator and the '**union**' method.

Example with '**__in**':

```
user_id = 1
Project.objects.filter(creaters__in=[user_id]) | Project.objects.filter(workers__in=[user_id])
```

And with the '**union**' method:

```
user_id = 1
creator_projects = Project.objects.filter(creaters__id=user_id)
worker_projects = Project.objects.filter(workers__id=user_id)
creator_projects.union(worker_projects)
```

More info about [union](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#union) method and [__in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) operator.